# Ending position out of bounds: 15 in apex Test class

Tags: apex, failing-tests

I'm new to apex and stuck with below test class issue. Below is my apex method

VF code that calls `method1` through `actionFunction and apex:param`

```
<apex:actionFunction name="deleteRec" action="{!method1}">
    <apex:param name="param" assignTo="{!recId}" value=""/>
</apex:actionFunction>
```

Method onLoad is referred in apex:repeat in VF page and displayed in the form of link. When the link is clicked, `recordId__c(18 char)` value is assigned to variable `recId`.

```
public class class1{
    public String recId{get;set;}
    public List<object1__c> recList = new List<object1__c>();
    public class1(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        recId = '';
        varId = controller.getId();
        onLoad();
    }
    public List<object1__c> onLoad() {

        recList = [SELECT field1__c, field2__c, recordId__c FROM object1__c WHERE Case__c =:varId];
        return recList;

    }
    public void method1(){
        List<object1__c> objList = new List<object1__c>();
        String recToDel = recId.substring(0, 15);
        objList = [SELECT Id, rec_ID__c FROM object1__c WHERE rec_ID__c =:recToDel];
        if(objList.size()>0){
            delete objList;
        }
    }
}
```

> Note: value to recId is passed from VF page.
>
> I'm getting System.StringException: Ending position out of bounds: 15
>   error while call method1 from my test class

```
@isTest
public class testclass{
    @isTest
    public static void method1Test(){
        //Inserting Sample case rec
        Case dummyCase = new Case();

        testCase.Subject = 'testCase Subject';
        testCase.Description = 'testCase Description';
        testCase.Status = 'Closed - Solved';
        testCase.Language__c ='English';
        insert testCase;

        object1__c objRec = new object1__c();
        objRec.field1__C__c = testCase.Id; 
        objRec.recordId__c = 'Ka1234567890123';
        objRec.field2__C= 'abc';

        insert objRec; 

        String recToDel = objRec.recordId__c.substring(0, 15);
        system.assertEquals('Ka1234567890123', recToDel);

        object1__c objRec = new object1__c();                
        objRec = [SELECT field1__c, recordId__c FROM object1__c WHERE recordId__c =:recToDel];
        delete objRec;
ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(dummyCase);
        method1Class controller = new method1Class(sc);
        controller.method1(); // Getting error here
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include the code where recId is set in your controller class please? I think that's the reason why you are getting this error.

Comment: is `recId` a URL param to the page?

Comment: I've updated both controller and test class code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to manually set your rec1 variable in your unit test method.

Something like:

```
method1Class controller = new method1Class(sc);
controller.recId = objRec.Id;
controller.method1();
```

Depending on what you want to test, you might want to set it to be a different sobject's id. But you got the idea here.